# Ionic 2 - How do I use a cordova plugin that is not available in ionic native

Tags: cordova, arduino, ionic2, cordova-plugins, rfduino

With the following command I installed a cordova plugin on my ionic2 project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-rfduino
```

This plugin is not available in the Ionic Native. How can I use the plugin in an ionic page? Can I export it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it the following way:

0 - Install your plugin

1- 
    npm install typings --global

2 - On typings/index.d.ts put the following code:

```
    interface Window {
       plugins: any;
    }
```

3 - Then use the window the following way inside the page or component:

```
  constructor(platform: Platform) {
platform.ready().then(() => {


 var blabla = window['cordova_plugin_that_was_installed'].function();

   });
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you install the plugin you can use it from the global `window` object, but the typescript will not understand what is `rfduino` object and its type, so you have to declare it to the declarations file which is located in `src/declarations.d.ts`, so you will be able to use it by just adding this line of code in that file

```
declare var rfduino: any;
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is not enough. I fixed it - look at my answer.